# Boost Logger Static Linking: Not Working

Tags: c++, boost, static-linking, boost-log

I have a Qt application that uses the boost logger library. I want to make it a standalone. However, after I managed the libraries for static linking, the application is still dependent on boost libraries.
The libraries that I included are:

```
    ..../boost_1_61_0_b1/stage/lib/libboost_regex.a
    ..../boost_1_61_0_b1/stage/lib/libboost_log_setup.a
    ..../boost_1_61_0_b1/stage/lib/libboost_thread.a
    ..../boost_1_61_0_b1/stage/lib/libboost_log.a
    ..../boost_1_61_0_b1/stage/lib/libboost_system.a
    ..../boost_1_61_0_b1/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a
```

The application compiles( after countless attempts). However, when I use ldd tool, it shows boost libraries on the dependency list.

Note: I have to define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK. Otherwise, it doesn't link.

Is there any way not to use this macro and overcome the dependency problem ? If not, what solutions do you suggest to circumvent this problem?

Comment: Compile all boost libraries as static libs in 1st place. I'm pretty sure there's a bjam option you can use too achieve that.

Comment: But I do have both .a and .so files under /stage/libs. Should I split them off ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default on modern UNIX-like systems gcc links with shared libraries by default. In order to force static linking you can either add `-static` to your linking command line (see the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)) or make sure gcc doesn't find the shared libraries but only finds the static libraries (e.g. move the shared libraries to a separate directory while you're linking your project). Note that `-static` will make all libraries linked statically, including libstdc++.

Alternatively, you can specify the static libraries directly, without the `-l` switch. You will have to use the full path to the libraries though, so instead of

```
gcc ... -lboost_log ...
```

you would write

```
gcc ... ..../boost_1_61_0_b1/stage/lib/libboost_log.a ...
```

In any case, you should *not* define `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` because this macro means exactly the opposite - that you intend to link with Boost *shared* libraries.

Comment: I tried bjam -static then I linked to the .a libraries and It worked. I don't know if it's a Qt .pro problem or what but it seems that when there were both .a and .so libraries in the same path, it links to the .so even if it's specified otherwise. Thanks anyways